# How do I generate a random number in an XML file?

Tags: android, rotation

I'm making an object that spins when a button is pushed and I want it to spin 360 degrees then continue to spin for a random number so it lands somewhere different every time. This is what I have in my xml file (called anime) and it spins the 360 perfectly.

```
    <rotate 
    android:fromDegrees = "0"
    android:toDegrees = "360"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY = "50%"
    android:startOffset = "0"
    android:duration = "1000" />
```

i just need help with the logic behind generating a random value of it.

also this is how it appears in my java

```
 but_spin = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.spin_but);
 final Context mcontext = this;
 but_spin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
      ImageView animated = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
      anime = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mcontext, R.anim.anime);
      animated.startAnimation(anime);  
      }}
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it in XML. Code the animation manually,

```
static final Random R = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
...
Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0, 360 + R.nextInt(180));
ImageView animated = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
animated.startAnimation(a);
```

Refer to the [`RotateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) API docs for details.

Comment: Does the pivotX and pivotY need to be set to 50% or this that default ?

Comment: refer to the javadocs (linked) for the constructor that accepts pivot values.

Comment: The animation works fine, however i have a touch listener also active on the big_button, so it can be "manually" rotated, and the animation disrupts the listener and causes more problems for my code... can i send my project to anyone to have a look at?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate a random number in XML file.

Create a RotateAnimation from code.

Answer (score 0):

XML layout files contain static data that doesn't change during execution of your app. You will need to use Java code to generate a random number and rotate your drawable based on that value.